# model averaging gamm4 models and reporting the results

Tags: r, gam

I have constructed three alternative models using `gamm4`and would like to compare and report parameter estimates for the different predictor variables that are represented in all my three models. I'm using `MuMIn` to calculate parameter estimates in a model averaging procedure.

However, parameter estimates are returned for each variable and knot level rather than an overall estimate value for each predictor (for example, when `k=5`, it returns parameter estimates for `k1` to `k4`. I am interested in among other things comparing the overall effect/importance of each predictor and therefore not interested in estimates at each knot.

1) Is there a way to obtain an overall estimate associated with each predictor, regardless of the knot level? that way one could use such an estimate (when standardized) to infer the overall effect as you would do with say when using 'glmm').

2) In general how should one report estimates from `gamm4`/`gamm` models or rephrased - which components from these models should one report and can these be used in model averaging?

```
require(MuMIn)
library(gamm4)
library(mgcv)

#GENERATE DATA
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,scale=2)
dat<-subset(dat, select=c(x0,x1,x2,x3,f) )
dat$g <- as.factor(sample(1:20,400,replace=TRUE))#random factor
dat$yb<-runif(400)#yb ranges between 0-1 hence fitted with beta family

##FITTING gamm4 MODELS
m1<-gamm4(yb~s(x0, k=5)+s(x1, k=5)+s(x2, k=5)+s(x3, k=5),family=Gamma(link='log'),data=dat,random=~(1|g))
m2<-gamm4(yb~s(x1, k=5)+s(x2, k=5)+s(x3, k=5),family=Gamma(link='log'),data=dat,random=~(1|g))
m3<-gamm4(yb~s(x0, k=5)+s(x2, k=5)+s(x3, k=5),family=Gamma(link='log'),data=dat,random=~(1|g))

#same as above BUT using a function wrapper UGamm required by model.avg function from MuMIn package

m1a<-uGamm(yb~s(x0, k=5)+s(x1, k=5)+s(x2, k=5)+s(x3, k=5),family=Gamma(link='log'),data=dat,random=~(1|g), lme4=TRUE)
m2a<-uGamm(yb~s(x1, k=5)+s(x2, k=5)+s(x3, k=5),family=Gamma(link='log'),data=dat,random=~(1|g), lme4=TRUE)
m3a<-uGamm(yb~s(x0, k=5)+s(x2, k=5)+s(x3, k=5),family=Gamma(link='log'),data=dat,random=~(1|g), lme4=TRUE)

#create a list of models
models<-list(m1a,m2a,m3a)

#average the models
average.models<-model.avg(models)
```